# After truncate , we can not rollback data in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sqltransaction

I have a table named `a` that has 26 rows:

```
Select * from a
```

Output is 26

```
Begin Tran
Truncate table a
Select * from a
```

Output is zero rows

```
Rollback Tran
Select * from a
```

Output is again 26 rows

Truncate is ddl command we cannot perform rollback operation then why we get same number of rows after rollback ?

Please confirm in detail.

Comment: Where `commit` ?

Comment: @yogesh: yes after commit rollback why we get same number of rows 26

Comment: @ankush there is no evidence of a commit in your transaction.

Comment: @P.Salmon:yes same I want to confirm ....we can't perform rollback

Comment: @Ankush. . . Your third query should not display result. BTW, it should be in Operational stage. As you didn't specify `commit`. So, it is still in operation stage.

Comment: Oops thanks yogesh got it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, a `TRUNCATE` can be rolled back in a transaction in SQL Server. There are actually only a few things that can't be rolled back with a transaction in SQL Server. For example, you can even roll back other DDL statements (such as the `DROP` and `CREATE` below):

```
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Table1 (I int);
CREATE TABLE dbo.Table2 (I int);
GO
WITH N AS (
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N))
INSERT INTO dbo.Table1
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
FROM N N1, N N2, N N3, N N4;

WITH N AS (
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N))
INSERT INTO dbo.Table2
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
FROM N N1, N N2, N N3, N N4;
GO

BEGIN TRANSACTION SampleTran;

TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.Table1;

CREATE TABLE dbo.Table3 (I int);

INSERT INTO dbo.Table3
SELECT I
FROM dbo.Table2;

DROP TABLE dbo.Table2;

ROLLBACK TRANSACTION SampleTran;
GO

--Contains 10,000 rows
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Table1;
GO
--Still exists
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Table2;
GO
--Doesn't exist
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Table3;
GO

--Clean up    
DROP TABLE dbo.Table1;
DROP TABLE dbo.Table2;
```

Despite "intellisense" probably telling you that `dbo.Table2` doesn't exist in the lower batches, it does, as that transaction was rolled back. (Intellisense will also think that `dbo.Table3` still exists, which it will not.)

Unlike the myth that people seem to believe, `TRUNCATE` is logged. Unlike `DELETE`, however, `TRUNCATE` deletes the **pages** the data is stored on, not the individual rows. A log of what pages are deleted is still written, so a `TRUNCATE` can still be rolled back, as the deletion of those pages is simply not committed.

Answer (score 3):

Truncate does not delete the actual data, it just de-allocates the pages. The de-allocations are logged, enable the transaction to rolled back by simply re-allocating the original pages - data intact :-)

Answer (score 2):

I think the misunderstanding is, that in Oracle TRUNCATE can't be rolled back.

In SQL-Server Truncate just deletes the whole table-rows with more efficiency

Comment: *" In SQL-Server Truncate just deletes the whole table-rows with more efficiency"* this is quite untrue. `DELETE` and `TRUNCATE` simply work very differently. I wouldn't say that `TRUNCATE` is "more efficient" than `DELETE`, because the they aren't really comparable. `TRUNCATE`  actually deletes the pages the data is stored on, where as `DELETE`deletes each row.

Comment: From the doucmentation: TRUNCATE TABLE is similar to the DELETE statement with no WHERE clause; however, TRUNCATE TABLE is faster and uses fewer system and transaction log resources. Maybe it's a bit simplyfied but quite close